# How to use awk script to generate a file

Tags: awk

I have a very large compressed file(**dataFile.gz**) that I want to generate  another file using cat and awk. So using cat to view the contents and then piping it to awk to generate the new file.
The contents of compressed as like below

```
Time,SequenceNumber,MsgType,MsgLength,CityOrign,RTime
7:20:13,1,A,34,Tokyo,0
7:20:13,2,C,35,Nairobi,7:20:14
7:20:14,3,E,30,Berlin,7:20:15
7:20:16,4,A,34,Berlin,7:20:17
7:20:17,5,C,35,Denver,0
7:20:17,6,D,33,Helsinki,7:20:18
7:20:18,7,F,37,Tokyo,0
….
….
….
```

For the new file, I want to generate, I only want the Time, MsgType and RTime. Meaning columns 0,2 and 5. And for column 5, if the value is 0, replace it with the value at column 0. i.e replace RTime with Time

```
Time,MsgType,RTime
7:20:13,A,7:20:13
7:20:13,C,7:20:14
7:20:14,E,7:20:15
7:20:16,A,7:20:17
7:20:17,C,7:20:17
7:20:17,D,7:20:18
7:20:18,F,7:20:18
```

This is my script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 

BEGIN {FS=","

    print %0,%2,

    if ($5 == "0") {
        print $0
    } else {
        print $5
    }
}
```

My question is, will this script work and how do I call it. Can I call it on the terminal like below?

```
zcat dataFile.gz | <awk script> > generatedFile.csv
```

Comment: Since you want to apply awk script on every line, remove `BEGIN` and it should work.

Comment: like `zcat dataFile.gz | awk -f yourscript.awk > youroutputfile` I fail to see how your script will get the output you want though. Surely just `zcat dataFile.gz | awk -F"," '{print $1, $3, $6}' > youroutputfile` would suffice.

Comment: For something this simple, there's no reason to bother with scripting the awk.  Just do `zcat dataFile.gz | awk '!$5{$5 = $1} {print $1, $2, $5}' FS=, OFS=, > output.csv`

Comment: Note that `$0` is not "column 0", it is the whole line.  Columns are counted 1-based.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took the time to comment. I found a solution because of YOU...Big thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` index starts with `1` and `$0` represents full record. So column numbers would be `1, 3, 6`.

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} !$6{$6=$1} {print $1, $3, $6}' file
```

```
Time,MsgType,RTime
7:20:13,A,7:20:13
7:20:13,C,7:20:14
7:20:14,E,7:20:15
7:20:16,A,7:20:17
7:20:17,C,7:20:17
7:20:17,D,7:20:18
7:20:18,F,7:20:18
```

Comment: This helped. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. And also thanks to all who made a comment so far..I'm very grateful

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. A bit shorter version of @anubhava sir's solution. This one is NOT having assignment to 6th field it only checks if that is zero or not and accordingly it prints the values.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1, $3, $6==0?$1:$6}' Input_file
```